# How to reindex after adding a new field

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

I added a new field. This field is present in pretty much all the data rows that Azure search will be returned and needs to be indexed.

1. Changed the VIEW that returns rows to AzureSearch to return a new row ("name")
2. Added a new field to the Index ("name")
3. Verified via Search Explorer that "name" field is returned in results for that index. It is currently always null (as expected) in the results.

Now how do I trigger a full reindex so the "name" field will contain values for ALL the rows, and not just for the NEW rows going forward.

(of course, I could delete the index and recreate a new one and repoint my code to the new index, but it seems needlessly brute force!)

Comment: You could reset the indexer.

Comment: I had to uncheck the "Allow Tracking" option; then SAVE. Then add the "Allow tracking" back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, reset the indexer's change tracking state using [Reset Indexer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/reset-indexer). You can also reset the indexer in Azure Portal or using .NET client SDK.

Comment: So how to do this without causing an outage?
1) Index1 is my current index
2) I add a new field to the data source; now I need it to be in the index.
3) Create new Index2 is basically the same schema as Index1 + new field. Let this index run and become current.
4) Switch my code to use the new Index2; deploy this code everywhere.
5) Delete Index1
(rinse/repeat for future field adds)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can add the new field to an existing index, so that you avoid any search downtime for your app